# I'm not getting push notifications from AWS Pinpoint in react native (android) project

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I have followed official [AWS Pinpoint guide](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/push-notifications), and I was not able to receive Push notification on my device.

My steps:

1. My Firebase project configured correctly, I was able to receive push notification from Firebase console
2. I enabled Push notifications in AWS Pinpoint console and added API key and Sender ID there
3. I did these commands in the project:

`npm install @aws-amplify/pushnotification --save`
`react-native link @aws-amplify/pushnotification`

4. Added configuration for analytics and push notifications in App.js

```
Amplify.configure({

    Auth: {
        region: 'xxx',
        userPoolId: 'xxx',
        userPoolWebClientId: 'xxx',
        mandatorySignIn: true
    },
    API: {
        endpoints: [{
            name: "xxx",
            endpoint: "xxxx",
            custom_header: async () => ({ Authorization: await getAuthorizationToken() })
        }]
    },
    Analytics: {
      disabled: false,
      AWSPinpoint: {
        appId: 'xxxxxx',
        region: 'xxxx',
      }
    }
});

PushNotification.configure({
  appId: 'xxxx',
  region: 'xxxx',
});
```

5. Added in componentDidMount in `App.js` method `onRegister`:

```
componentDidMount(){
  PushNotification.onRegister((token) => {
    console.log('in app registration', token);
  });
}
```

6. After Sign In added this `updateEndpoint` method:

```
Analytics.updateEndpoint({
  address: 'xxxx',
  channelType: 'GCM',
  userId: '1',
})
```

7. I was trying to create Test campaign in `AWS Pinpoint` console, but console didn't see any devices and didn't send anything to the phones.

What I'm missing? How to make it work?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @desoss no, I ended up using OneSignal library for push notifications.